# How to change defaults for featherlight.js Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, featherlight.js

When using featherlight as a wordpress plugin, how can I change default options without breaking theme, etc.?

I see that the only js loaded on my page is 
`/wp-content/plugins/wp-featherlight/js/wpFeatherlight.pkgd.min.js?ver=1.3.0`

Currently I need to add all these attributes to every link:

```
data-featherlight="iframe" 
data-featherlight-iframe-frameborder="0" 
data-featherlight-iframe-allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
data-featherlight-iframe-allowfullscreen="true" 
data-featherlight-iframe-style="position:fixed;background:#000;border:none;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"
```

...which is a lot of repeated overhead. How can I set these as defaults for all my iframe lightboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can set defaults globally like this:

```
$.extend($.featherlight.defaults, {
  type: "iframe",
  iframeFrameborder: "0",
  iframeAllow: "autoplay; encrypted-media",
  iframeAllowfullscreen: "true",
  iframeStyle: "position:fixed;background:#000;border:none;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;",
});
```

Comment: Great, but how do I add that in WordPress? Do I need to use an 'add custom js' plugin? I don't want this to break with updates. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, sounds like it. That will be supported forever.